# Unable to see nested content as data type in umbraco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I am an umbraco novice and I have added the Nested Content package (0.3.0), but when I click Developer > Data Types, it does not appear in the list of available items. Screenshot showing the installed packaged and the list below.

Couldn't find any documentation on the nested content page. Any help greatly appreciated. Thank you
[image: Umbraco Nested Content Data Type not showing]

Answer (score 1):

Could be a caching issue, and the DataType manifest hasn't been picked up. Clear your browser's cache and reload the back office. Does the DataType show up in the dropdown then?

If not, check that the site has files in the /App_Plugins/NestedContent/. there should be a package manifest file and several folders containing the CSS/JS and Views for the plugin. If those files aren't present, you may need to re-install the plugin.

Comment: thanks. the package was there but the only way I could get nested content to show up was by installing the nuget package. After that, it showed up.